# Displaying images stored in the server using 'path/filename' stored in the database

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I just wanna ask if someone can explain to me why I cant display my images to the website that I'm creating. I stored the 'path/filename' in one of the columns in the database. While the image image is stored in the server.

```
<?php foreach $data as $val{?>
   <img src="<?php echo base_url();?><?php echo $val->file;?>">
<?php }?>
```

Controller

```
$path = $_FILES["addFile"]["name"];
$extension = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$file_sc = 'uploads/screenshots/'.date("Ymdhms.").$extension;

$new_name = date("Ymdhms").".".$extension;
$target_dir = "./uploads/screenshots/";
$target_file = $target_dir.$new_name;

$type = $_FILES["addFile"]["type"];
$allowed = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');

if($_FILES["addFile"]["name"]){
    if(!in_array($type,$allowed)){
        echo 'File type is not allowed.';
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["addFile"]["tmp_name"],$target_file);
        $this->MyModel->add($file_sc);
    }
```

Model

```
function add_kudos($file_sc)
{
  $query =  $this->db->query("insert into tbl_kudos(file) values('$file_sc');
}
```

This is how it looks like in the database -> 'uploads/screenshots/20170224040231.jpg'

The file name in the server ->20170224040231.jpg

The image is not showing. Even if my url is correct.
Can someone explain to me why it's like this? I am new to this.

Comment: no enough code to support this

Comment: wait i'll edit it

Answer (score 0):

First filename is different to second filename!

You can use `urlencode()` then print your image URL

Comment: It echoes the same path to the image. Why cant I view it in the web? But if I go to the directory using the url, I can view the image. The path that it echos in the code is the same with the url.

Comment: there is any .htaccess file in your root?

Answer (score 0):

create a php file like this named showimg.php:

```
<?php
    $img = $_REQUEST['img'];
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); 
    $mime=finfo_file($finfo, $img) ;
    finfo_close($finfo);
    header("Content-type: $mime");
    $fp = fopen($img, 'rb');
    fpassthru($fp);
?>
```

use your code to get the path of the image that you want to show from the DB in a var named $myimgpath  and then use something like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url()."showimg.php?img=".$myimgpath;?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php foreach ( $data as $val ) { ?>
   <img src="<?php echo base_url( $val->file ); ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: you should use double quotation.

Comment: double qutation will not work as it is used in    src attribute.

Comment: `'$val->file'` is a string, isn't variable